# How to pass cloud firestore field value to new variable in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have new variable called var lat and var long in index.js. For getting firebase value, I have used this code

```
  var lat;
  var long;

 var cityRef = 
db.collection('UsersCurrentBookings').doc('3Xg6ujHMINeElzdOD3JypcZBMHw2');
var getDoc = cityRef.get()
.then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());

    }
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting document', err);
});
```

My console output:

Document data: { city: 'Chennai',

country: 'India',

time: '10:35:57',

date: '2018-03-28',

token: 'deFFa4dBPlQ:APA91bF7hTjsSkk-l6fLaI939W0ISe2olO18OjCUZu4N9URr9QKW4xXBIyWyC1L9Vui1cawGkFaSV1M2yDG4ASJyeCtrwGyal0GmIgdciZeGVmNSUnvyddTLUPAxQlAsjpAHTJy4Lwqt',

address: 'Sri Aravinthar St, Sholinganallur, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600119, India',

Currentlat: '12.8710994',

Currentlong: '80.2225558',

I want pass console output value currentlat and currentlong value into new variable of lat and long.

After getting value from UsersCurrentBookings db then how to insert value into db.collection(DriversCurrentBookins) and parameter value lat, long and token.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly access data from the JSON response and if you want, you can parse the data to Float type too using Javascript Global function `parseFloat();`

```
var lat = parseFloat(doc.data().Currentlat);
var lng = parseFloat(doc.data().Currentlong);
```

******UPDATE******

To add data to your Mongo database, you can use libraries like

[MongooseJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) : `// This uses a model based structure, can be a little difficult to understand at first.`

or

[MongoJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongojs)

******UPDATE Ignore previous one******

```
const tokenField = data.getData().token
const ref = db.collection().doc(tokenField);

var jsonData = {
    'lat' : lat,
    'lng' : lng
}

ref.set(jsonData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its works like charm!!. And i have updated my question can you check it.

Comment: here i am using cloud firestore not mongo database

Comment: Oh I haven't used Firestore for Node yet, I ll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

called set data into usercurrentbooking collection db

```
var cityRef = 
 db.collection('UsersBookingRequest').doc('9DjekLkfFmTeLfkyZQAeezVriv02');
 var getDoc = cityRef.get()
.then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        lat = doc.data().Currentlat;
        long = doc.data().Currentlong;
        UID = doc.data().UID;
        // token = doc.data().token;
        address = doc.data().address;
        date = doc.data().date;
        time = doc.data().time;

        console.log(lat);
        console.log(long);
        console.log(UID);
        // console.log(token);
        console.log(address);
        console.log(date);
        console.log(time);

        var data = {

                 lat: lat,
                 long: long,
                 UID: UID,
                 address: address,
                 date: date,
                 time: time
                 // token: token


                    };

                // Add a new document in collection "cities" with ID 'LA'
        var setDoc = 
 db.collection('DriversCurrentBookings').doc(doc.data().UID).set(data);

    }
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting document', err);
});
```